# jquery on click event firing inside false conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Can someone please explain to me why the on click event is firing inside of this condition that evaluates to false?

```
function getHeight() {      

    if( checkWindowWidth() ) {  // Returns false    
        console.log("works"); // Not logged since condition is false

        $( ".class" ).on( "click", function() {    
            // Do some things. 
            console.log("why working?"); // Is logged, but why?  

        } else {    
            // Do other stuff    
        }

    }

}

getHeight();

$(window).resize(function() {
    getHeight();
});
```

How would I write this so it would not fire inside a false condition?

### Update:

It looks like moving the `.on` outside of `getHeight()` and then adding the condition within `.on` does what I need.

Comment: I'm guessing it returned true at sometime, and when the event is bound, it's bound. You probably wanted to put the condition ***inside*** the event handler

Comment: Please show the checkWindowWidth() function.

Comment: Please post valid code. This won't run at all.

Comment: A click event inside a named function is weird in general. I think you are confusing vanilla javascript syntax with jquery syntax

Comment: @adeneo yes this might be true, however, I'm calling the getHeight function again on resize. So at one window size it's true, but on resize it's false.

Comment: Once its true the on click event handler is registered, then that handler will be called whenever the user clicks on an element with .class class.

Comment: Also your missing a closing brace and bracket

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".class" ).on( "click", function() {    
            // Do some things. 
            console.log("why working?"); // Is logged, but why?  

}
```

This code means you are registering the `click` event and would after that whenever click happens it would log, all it needs is just run once. So basically you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I follow. Why would it be doing anything at all when it's in a condition that's not even true? Shouldn't the on click do nothing?

Comment: `.on` register the callback function to be called whenever the click happens. So in your code even once the  condition is true its running this code and then after that it no longer needs any condition to run

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that **getHeight** is not being called for **checkWindowWidth() = true** before **checkWindowWidth() = false**

Binding of an event does not depend upon the scope

Answer (score 0):

Within the getheight if statement you are binding an event handler function. Once bound this function will be called whenever the event is triggered, no longer is it dependent on the getheight function.